How to enable autoplay / change slides of PowerPoint presentation with Web Viewer?
I want to slide show a PowerPoint presentation (.pptx) on a web page.
I've found the most popular option for this is using Office Web Viewer: https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=URL_to_PPTX.
But the problem that it's not switching slides, even in full screen mode.
I'm wondering if there some documentation for this service? For example what are the other supported URL parameters besides src or is there any JavaScript API?
Otherwise, would like to know what other free web apps exist, similar to Office Web Viewer, but with autoplay option.
